# Rails: MySQL2 Error when hitting the finder of a model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

with Rails I hit this:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["character = ?", character])
```

`character` is a Fixnum, as you can see by the way it is translated for the sql. A Fixnum is expected.

Then I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 5)'
at line 1: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (character = 5)
```

I'm somewhat confused and absolutely do not get what might be wrong with this line of sql.

Please help.

Yours

Joern

Comment: I already tried checking > and < with character -1 and +1 - all didn't help, same error

Comment: and I already set the encoding explicitly to UTF8 and saved the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `character` is a keyword in mysql.  If you escape it in backticks it should work, eg

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["`character` = ?", character])
```

When you do a rails find like

```
User.where(:character => character)
```

as Rich Peck suggests, then rails automatically escapes the names of all fields to prevent this problem:  you can see it do this in your log.

EDIT:  you might find it less hassle in the long run to change the name of your column.

Answer (score 0):

**ActiveRecord**

If using Rails 4, you should use this to look up multiple records:

```
User.where character: character
```

If you want to load a specific record, you can just use [`.find`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by) like this:

```
User.find_by character: character
```

--

**Specific**

I think your error is more an ActiveRecord issue than a `Fixnum` one - the fact you're using that data to look up the records shouldn't have any bearing.

I could be wrong, but I think the bottom line is your use of the ActiveRecord methods you've defined.